Why is my code implemented in latches?
I am starting to design in a HDL. So, I'm designing a simple test, where variable "var" is an and of each "partial" row. However, when I synthesize this, I see that the RTL generated is quite big, implementing a latch for this loop. My code:
reg [N-1:0] var;
wire [N*N-1:0] input;
always @ (*) begin
  var= {N{1'b1}};
  for(i = 1; i < N; i = i + 1) begin
    for(j = 0; j < i; j = j + 1) begin   
      var[i] = var[i] & !input[j*N+i];
    end
  end
end

I assumed that this code would be optimized, as what I want to do is:
var[1] = input[0*N+1];
var[2] = input[0*N+2] & input[1*N+2];
var[3] = input[0*N+3] & input[1*N+3] & input[2*N+3];


Why is this happening and how do I change the code to implement a simple combinational circuit?
Also, insight or recommendations on how to avoid latches or best practices would be appreciated.
Edit:
I am using Genus by Cadence.

What synthesis tool are you using, and how have you instantiated the code (e.g. surrounding module and variable declarations)? For example, Quartus infers exactly what you expect to get, and no latches: inferred RTL.

The code you show does not match the equations you want. var[1] should have 2 input terms inverted. Please be precise.

The always @(*) says this is a combinatorial block, but it is supposed to modify a reg?

@SimonRichter reg is a misnomer, it's simply the net type used in procedural blocks, it doesn't imply a register.

I am using Genus by cadence. Also, I changed the equation of what I wanted to do; there was a mistake.
